# Is there a simple client side storage solution to save data from a .net mobile website onto a mobile device?

Tags: .net, mobile

I have a .net website that's mobile responsive. 
There is some data generated on a page of the website that I would like the user to be able to click a button and that data would get stored on the mobile device.
There are a few articles around but hoping there might be a simple implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe saving data into [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies)?

A mobile browser is still a browser, depending on which browser version you can even implement [html5 local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

About the tel: links that send you to the phone call app, or maybe you can do it using [Deep Links](http://mobiledeeplinking.org/), opening some notes app or something like.

If what you want your user be able to save can be saved as a file, you can just use a download link.